# Chrome Extension API: Add URL to 3rd Party cookies exception list

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Is there a way in the Chrome Extension API to add an exception URL for 3rd party cookies?

I have looked at content settings and privacy and found nothing. I know I can force allow 3rd party cookies altogether, but that seems invasive to the user.

Answer (score 1):

It's not even possible to do it manually by going to chrome://settings/contentExceptions#cookies

If the "*Block third-party cookies*" setting is enabled, you cannot add any exception! You can only disable this option and allow all third-party cookies at the same time.

Pretty stupid from Google, I guess they're trying to force users to not block third-party cookies.

I'm always blocking third-party cookies, but because it wasn't working for attachments in gmail (emails are served from `mail.google.com` and attachements from `mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com`) I wanted to add those two domains to the exception list but cookies would still remain blocked. Only disabling the "*Block third-party cookies*" option would allow cookies to be set from third-party domains.

Hope that clears things up. Cheers!